# Step numbering in XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Been struggling with this for a bit and now going to ask for help. I am trying to get the correct number for a step to appear when referencing it on PDF output when using XSL-FO. With help previously gotten here I have other references working as desired. These particular tags are giving me trouble.

This is for a fault isolation tree in the S1000D aerospace publication spec:

```
<isolationStep id="step4"><isolationStepQuestion>Check for burnt-out lamps. Are lamps good?</isolationStepQuestion><isolationStepAnswer><yesNoAnswer><yesAnswer nextActionRefId="step6"/><noAnswer nextActionRefId="step8"/></yesNoAnswer></isolationStepAnswer></isolationStep>
```

As you can see there is an answer section for the question. Those answers have refIds to other steps. In the PDF I am getting the steps to be numbered correctly, but when rendering the answers I am getting this:

[image]

The XSL-FO used for the questions, answers, and the attempt to number to answer referenced steps:

```
<xsl:template match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd">
    <xsl:for-each select="note">
        <fo:block font-weight="bold">Note</fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="caution">
        <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center">CAUTION</fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="warning">
        <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center">WARNING</fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <fo:block id="{@id}" padding="5pt" font-size="10pt">
        <!-- border-style="solid"
              border-width=".1mm"-->
        <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->
        <fo:list-block space-after="2mm">
            <fo:list-item>
                <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:number level="multiple" count="isolationMainProcedure/isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd" format="1."/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                    <fo:block>
                        <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>-->
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="count(action) &gt; 1">
                                <xsl:for-each select="action">
                                    <fo:list-block space-after="2mm">
                                        <fo:list-item>
                                            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                                            <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:number format="a."/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </fo:list-item-label>
                                            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                                            <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </fo:list-item-body>
                                        </fo:list-item>
                                    </fo:list-block>
                                    <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:for-each select="action">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="isolationStepQuestion"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="isolationStepAnswer"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
        </fo:list-block>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd" mode="nbr">
    <xsl:variable name="origNbr">
        <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1"/>            
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$origNbr"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="isolationStepQuestion">
    <fo:block font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="yesNoAnswer">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="yesAnswer">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@nextActionRefId"/>
    <fo:block space-before="4pt" space-after="4pt" keep-with-previous="always">
        <fo:inline><xsl:text>Yes: Go to </xsl:text>
            <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@nextActionRefId}" color="blue">Step  <!--<xsl:value-of select="$yesref2"/>-->
                <!--ancestor::isolationMainProcedure-->
                <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="an../../../.././isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd[@id=$yesref]" mode="nbr"/> ancestor::isolationMainProcedure[1]/-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd[@id=$ref]" mode="nbr"/>
            </fo:basic-link></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="noAnswer">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@nextActionRefId"/>
    <fo:block keep-with-previous="always">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:text>No: Go to </xsl:text>
            <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@nextActionRefId}" color="blue">Step 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd[@id=$ref]" mode="nbr"/>
            </fo:basic-link></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="isolationStepAnswer">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd" mode="nbr">
    <xsl:variable name="origNbr">
        <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1"/>            
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$origNbr"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, the links are working, and takes you to the correct location. I just am having issues getting it to number correctly.

This is an XSL 2.0 stylesheet. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `//isolationStep` is selecting every `isolationStep` in the document, so you're getting the number of each of them.

You might have been trying to have the effect of "`//isolationStep[@id=$ref] | //isolationProcedureEnd[@id=$ref]`, but you'd probably be better of using a key for looking up `isolationStep` and `isolationProcedureEnd` by their IDs.

---

Keys are defined at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key

You could define a key for lookup of `isolationStep` elements by their `@id` as a top-level element in the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="isolationSteps"
         match="isolationStep"
         use="@id" />
```

and in your template, use the `key()` function to find the `isolationStep` with the matching `@id` value:

```
<xsl:template match="yesAnswer">
    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="@nextActionRefId"/>
    <fo:block space-before="4pt" space-after="4pt" keep-with-previous="always">
        <fo:inline><xsl:text>Yes: Go to </xsl:text>
            <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@nextActionRefId}" color="blue">Step  <!--<xsl:value-of select="$yesref2"/>-->
                <!--ancestor::isolationMainProcedure-->
                <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="an../../../.././isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd[@id=$yesref]" mode="nbr"/> ancestor::isolationMainProcedure[1]/-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('isolationSteps', $ref)" mode="nbr"/>
            </fo:basic-link></fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with using keys for this, could show me how this could be implemented?

Comment: I added an (untested) example.

Comment: Didn't think it was really that simple. One question, the isolationStep and isolationProcedureEnd elements need to be counted at the same time, as they are siblings. Can the key match either or? I will test here momentarily. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that all you need is `<xsl:number count="*"/>` (or maybe `<xsl:number count="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd"/>` if there's other sibling elements).  In fact, that should be all that you need as the content of your `xsl:template`: you don't need the `xsl:variable` and `xsl:value-of` since `xsl:number` returns a text node anyway.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#numbering-based-on-position

Comment: Do `yesAnswer` and `noAnswer` also refer to `isolationProcedureEnd` elements?  If so, you'd need to change the `xsl:key/@match` to `match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd"` so you can also lookup `isolationProcedureEnd` elements.

Comment: Yes, the `yesAnswer` and `noAnswer` can refer to either element. I did make my key look for both, but it numbered them independent of one another. I am adjusting the count to "*" as you suggested and will see if i get a better result.

Comment: The key is just for finding the right element.  It's independent of using `xsl:number` to generate the number.  The bit in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#numbering-based-on-position about "If count attribute is not specified, then it defaults to the pattern that matches any node with the same node kind as the selected node and, if the selected node has an expanded-QName, with the same expanded-QName as the selected node." boils down to counting the same-named elements when `@count` is absent.

Comment: Have it figured out now. The key: `<xsl:key name="isoSteps" match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd" use="@id"/>` and the template: `<xsl:template match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd" mode="nbr">
  <xsl:variable name="origNbr">
   <xsl:number level="single" format="1" count="*"/>            
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$origNbr"/>
 </xsl:template>`  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can reduce your template to `<xsl:template match="isolationStep | isolationProcedureEnd" mode="nbr"><xsl:number count="*"/> </xsl:template>` since you're currently duplicating default values of the attributes and generating a text node from a variable that contains a text node.